# How to make a gooey apple pie?

Tags: pie, apples, filling

I really love the gooey consistency of frozen pies. i would like to replicate that texture in my home made recipes. Does anyone know a method of preparing the filling that would accomplish this? I have tested it with cornstarch but with no success.

Comment: Did you cook down the apples, sugar and cornstarch (and any spices) before filling the pie shell and baking?

Comment: Which cuts of apple (or combination of cuts) have you tried?

Comment: I have tried both cooking down the apples with sugar etc, and mixing it all together and adding it to the pie shell. I've tried firm apples, mostly granny smith and gala. I'm starting to think I'll have to resign myself to trial and error.

Comment: You might try either arrowroot or tapioca as a thickener, both of which are somewhat 'gluey.'. Arrowroot can take longer cooking times, tapioca much less. The result may be the gooey you're trying to achieve. The other thought is that pectin might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using potato starch instead of cornstarch. In my experience it definitely resulted in gooey pie filling. (Cherry in my case)